# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' slideout error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I have a slide out function giving me the above error in the chrome console. It sites the line `document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("overlay04"));` in my JS function. How do I avoid this? Thanks. [test_site_link](http://blog.dundaah.com/)

```js
function expandOverlay() {
  var overlay = document.createElement("div");
  overlay.setAttribute("id", "overlay04");
  overlay.setAttribute("class", "overlay04");
  document.body.appendChild(overlay);
  $(overlay).hide().fadeIn(80);
}

function restore() {
  document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("overlay04"));
}

// create menu variables
var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // toggle open class
    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

    // slide menu
    if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
      slideoutMenu.animate({
        left: "0px"
      }, 160);
      expandOverlay();
    } else {
      slideoutMenu.animate({
        left: -slideoutMenuWidth
      }, 160);
      restore();
    }
  });

});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  var box = document.getElementById('menu_s');
  if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box) {
    slideoutMenu.animate({
      left: -slideoutMenuWidth
    }, 160);
    restore();
    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
  }
});
```

Full code.

Comment: Use the debugger and you'll see `restore` is called from mouseup listener on the first click. Your algo is strange: the overlay is added so that the underlying button no longer receives any click events. There are several methods how to do it correctly. For example, make the overlay permanent and show/hide it, attach a click event to it that will animate the menu.

Comment: good idea let's see

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is div element with id 'overlay04' not available when you call the 'restore' function, its created in 'expandOverlay' function which is executed after 'restore' function

`document.getElementById("overlay04"`) will be `null`
this why you are getting TypeError

Solution:
Add a null check in 'restore' function

```
function restore() {
  var $overlay04 = document.getElementById("overlay04");
  if ($overlay04) {
    document.body.removeChild($overlay04);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, no more errors, however the link then requires multiple clicks to toggle open.